# Series representation of $2e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gre-exam

According to [GR9768](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%205.pdf), problem 37: $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{k^2}{k!} = 2e$$
Can someone please explain how to get started in showing that?

Comment: oops.. apparently that site hosting the sample also has solutions hidden in it.

Comment: See also: [What's the value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44113). Other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/44113) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{k!} = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{k}{(k - 1)!} = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{k + 1}{k!} = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k - 1)!} + \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = 2 \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = 2e$$

Comment: I wonder...how efficiently can use this to solve for $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{n!}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt it cannot. Look at the format of your series, $n$ is the summatory variable, but here the only thing you have control over in your desired series is $k$, unlike in the series for $e^x$ where you control the base rather than the exponent.

Comment: @AdamHughes I suppose you can get a recursive relationship for each value of $k$ though.

Answer (score 9):

Write the series

$$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^k\over k!}$$

Now apply the derivative and multiply by $x$ to get

$$x{d\over dx}(e^x) = xe^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {kx^k\over k!}$$

Now do it again

$$x{d\over dx} (xe^x) = e^x + xe^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {k^2x^k\over k!}$$

Now let $x=1$

> $$e^1+1\cdot e^1 =2e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {k^2\over k!}$$

Comment: Perhaps you could see my more general answer, which takes the essence of your answer to arbitrary naturals.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm well aware of the method you use, but it was wildly inappropriate for the op's context (tagged as GRE question) so I opted for an approach that he would be most easily able to understand. Generalities are nice for oneself, but don't always help explain something to a student without the right background.

Comment: Oh, GRE... hm... I've actually never seen that tag :D

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Let $x\mapsto e^x$:

$$e^{e^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{nx}}{n!}$$

It thus follows that

$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}e^{e^x}\bigg|_{x=0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{n!}$$

And by applying [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula), we find that

$$eB_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{n!}$$

Where $B_k$ is the $k$th Bell number.

This is famously known as [Dobiński's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula).